# how to create a hyperlink for the NSString variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone developemnt.

```
NSString myUrl = @"www.google.com";
```

I need to know how to create a hyperlink for the above NSString variable.

In the `MFMailComposeViewController` I need to use like below

```
[mailViewController setMessageBody:myUrl isHTML:YES];
```

Please help me out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make the `UILabel` into a `UIButton`, style it (use Custom type to get rid of button look). Then connect to an Action that opens safari.

The action should do this:

```
NSURL *url = [[[ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.example.com" ] autorelease]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```