# Hypertext in uilabel or uitextview

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uitextview

Is there any way to make a hypertext in the text for `UILabel` or `UITextView`?

Comment: You mean you want to use html?  I believe you have to use a WebView to interpret html.

Comment: or you can put transparent button with the text on it in that place... but prefer web view if you can...

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to do with UITextview. You can set the datadetectortype for UITextview.

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set any action on lable or textview, don't forget to check "User Interaction Enabled", make it transparent, and open a link on it!

Answer (score 0):

As of now I tried for UILabel hyper link by providing gesture on label and never tried for UITextView.But more convenient way is providing a button with an action method that is easy way.some more details may useful for your work [hyperlink providing from the NSString.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031255/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-for-the-nsstring-variable/4031521#4031521)